# C# Interacting with CLI Process - StandardInput Stops Executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, command-line, command-line-interface

I am trying to interact with a CLI using C# StandardInputs and StandardOutputs.

I've inserted break points before and after process.StandardInput.WriteLine() as well as before an after the StandardOutput loops.

When I step into process.StandardInput.WriteLine() the code immediately stops executing and focus is returned to my main form (winform). The breakpoint (or any other code) following process.StandardInput.WriteLine() is never executed.

The same thing happens when the very last process.StandardOutput.WriteLine() is called in the loop

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();

        process.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("connect vpn.service.domain.com");
        ...Additional code below
```

Same thing happens if I were to read StandardOutput with this loop before aprocess.StandardInput.WriteLine():

```
        string line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CLI Says: " + line);
        }
        ...Additional code below
```

I have also noticed that if I run the Cisco VPN CLI using a normal GUI command prompt I get this output:

```
  Copyright (c) 2004 - 2015 Cisco Systems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


  >> state: Disconnected
  >> state: Disconnected
  >> notice: Ready to connect.
  >> registered with local VPN subsystem.
  VPN>
```

But When I run process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() Loops I get this output. You can see all the extra blank lines and the extra "**VPN>**" prompts:

```
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 3.1.10010) .


Copyright (c) 2004 - 2015 Cisco Systems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.




  >> state: Disconnected


VPN> 
  >> state: Disconnected


VPN> 
  >> notice: Ready to connect.


VPN> 
  >> registered with local VPN subsystem.
```

Comment: I don't trust AutoFlush.  Try using process.StandardInput.Flush().  The AutoFlush uses timers that may be stopped when you are debugging.

Comment: Interesting, that fixed the issue for process.StandardInput.WriteLine(); but it did not fix the issue with the process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() loops. It is definitely not the issue with the loop itself because If I were to just list a bunch of process.StandardOuput.ReadLine()s instead of looping it will still stop executing the code after It hits the last one.

Comment: You never want on a stream that is not a file to test for null.  You are reading all the data in the stream and getting EOF which is setting the null condition so you never get into the while loop.

Comment: Basically you want to connect to a VPN, am I correct? If you have Cisco's `vpnclient.exe` you can achieve what you need in easier way

Comment: @jdweng The loop is actually working fine. It loops through until it tries to read the last line. Like I said, If I remove the loop and just like out 25 lines of Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()); It will get through 24 of them but on the last one code breaks out.

Comment: @MatteoUmili Yes, I have it. I just want to do it programatically

Comment: @Michael So can't you run programmatically that `exe` as you are doing now?

Comment: Check Line Terminators. Which ones are used and which is ReadLine expecting?

Comment: @MatteoUmili I can but I believe I need to use vpncli.exe to pass in various arguments to specify settings and credentials

Comment: @Fildor I'm not sure how you mean to do that?

Comment: The 25 read is followed by EOF which gives a null so you do not get into the while loop and read the last line.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to solve the same problem. calling vpncli.exe from c#. Can you tell me if you got this working?

Answer (score 3):

`process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "connect vpn.service.domain.com -s";
...
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(userDetails.UserName);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(userDetails.Password);`

I added -s and it worked for me (This expands the stdin to the console).